# How to mutate an element from the DOM and then return it to its original state in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseover, mouseout, mutation

I've made a function which cycles through the DOM of a targeted are (via `id`) to create a rollover functionality.

My problem lies within the `rollOver/rollOut` function. For some reason the environment where I run this script seems to mess with the `srcset` attribute.

This is the original:

```
function rollOver(elem) {
  (document.getElementById(elem).srcset =
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-hover-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$"),
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-hover-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$ 2x";
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  (document.getElementById(elem).srcset =
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$"),
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$ 2x";
}
```

rollOver:

```
path/to/image/eyes-on-you-desktop-hover-" + elem.slice(6) + ".jpg?$staticlink$"
```

rollOut:

```
path/to/image/eyes-on-you-desktop-" + elem.slice(6) +".jpg $staticlink$"
```

The elem variable comes from here...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  var rollOverCollectionA = document
    .getElementById("roll-over-collection-b")
    .getElementsByClassName("rollover");
  rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);

  var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    on("mouseover", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function () {
      rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
    });
    on("mouseout", `#${rollOverCollectionA[i].id}`, function () {
      rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id);
    });
  }
});
```

and its just the `#id` value on the elem which gets sliced to coincide with the element which is receiving focus.

I tried something like this:

```
  function rollOver(id, elem ) {
    elem.srcset = elem.srcset.splice(174, 0, '-hover');
    elem.srcset = elem.srcset.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
    document.getElementById(id).srcset = elem.srcset;
  }

  function rollOut(id, elem) {
    document.getElementById(id).srcset = elem.srcset;
  }
```

But what that does is continually add 'hover to the elem.srcset/string !

**UPDATE**

This is a working [demo](https://codepen.io/antonioOrtiz/pen/aQoMNQ).

**UPDATE**

This is an example of what is happening.

[image]

The rollover appends hover to the non-hover state, but then the next time you hover the src now has `xxx-1-hover-hover.jpg

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can store original as property of the element itself. Whole thing seems overly complex. Should be able to pass whole element into each function and not need `id`. Provide a runnable demo

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the question and provided a link above to a `codepen`, I agree it's getting complex, but that's because of the environment. The environment breaks what i did which should work.

Comment: What do you mean by *"environment breaks"*? Demo should represent what is actually sent to browser. Right now images don't show due to bad paths

Comment: I mean I can't understand why the `rollOut/rollOver` function as I originally wrote it with the `slice method` wouldn't work. When used, they spit back a path with no image name?! e.g. `path/to/image/.jpg`

Ah you're right, I'm behind a wall so you wouldn't be able to get to them.